# Distribute centers with autolayout

Tags: ios, macos, uiview, autolayout, nsview

Reducing the problem to the X axis to simplify.

Given an array of 2 or more views with a common ancestor, how can we use autolayout to distribute their X centers evenly so that:

- The first view is left aligned to the common ancestor.
- The last view is right aligned to the common ancestor.
- The X centers of the views are evenly distributed.

The array contains the views in order. Nothing else can be assumed of the views and their common ancestor. In particular:

- The views can have different sizes.
- The origin of the common ancestor may be different from (0,0).
- The width of the common ancestor or any the views might change at any time.

In code (using `UIView`, but the same would apply for `NSView`):

```
- (NSArray*)constraintsByDistributingCenterXOfViews:(NSArray*)views
{
    const NSInteger count = views.count;
    NSAssert(count >= 2, @"Array must contain at least 2 views");

    NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIView *sharedAncestor = [views sharedAncestor]; // Util method

    UIView *firstView = [views firstObject];
    [constraints addObject:[firstView constraintByAligningLeftToView:sharedAncestor]]; // Util method

    UIView *previousView = [self firstObject];
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < count - 1; i++)
    {
        UIView *currentView = views[i];
        NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = ? // What would go here?
        [constraints addObject:constraint];
        previousView = currentView;
    }

    UIView *lastView = [views lastObject];
    [constraints addObject:[lastView constraintByAligningRightToView:sharedAncestor]]; // Util method

    return constraints;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to arrange your views this way. I think the eye will be drawn to the the spaces between the views which will be uneven when you have equal spacing to the centers. This problem is pretty complex, especially if your ultimate goal is to do this in two dimensions. You first need to figure out which of your views is the widest, and if it has 2 neighbors, which of them is the wider to establish the minimum inter-center distance that won't cause the views to overlap. I agree with Michael Platt's comment; this isn't really a job for auto layout.

Comment: @rdelmar Distributing centers is a common design request. As an operation, it's widely used in Photoshop and Illustrator. This can't be done in autolayout is a valid answer, BTW. :)

Comment: Ok, I guess I just can't think of a circumstance where this would look good, but then I'm not a designer (and my artistic talents are close to nil). I think I may have been too hasty on ruling out auto layout though. I'm going to try something out. I'll post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. It creates spacers and adds constraints between the centers of the views on either side and the spacer's left and right edges. The method is set up assuming that you've created all your views, but have not added them to their superview yet. Call it like this,

```
[self equallySpaceCentersOfViews:@[l1,l2,l3,l4] inView:someView];
// add a constraint here to vertically place one of the views in someView (all the views have their centerY's equal)
```

Here is the method,

```
-(void)equallySpaceCentersOfViews:(NSArray *) views inView:(UIView *) superview {

    //create and add all the spacers to the superview
    NSMutableArray *spacers = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i =0; i<views.count - 1; i++) {
        UIView *spacer = [UIView new];
        spacer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [superview addSubview:spacer];
        [spacers addObject:spacer];
    }

    //Add all the views to the superview.
    for (UIView *obj in views) {
        [obj setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [superview addSubview:obj];
    }

    // Create the constraints to the two edges
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:views[0] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:0 toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:views.lastObject attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:0 toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:0]];

    //Create the constraints between the views and spacers
    [views enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:obj attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:spacers[idx] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:obj attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:spacers[idx] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:views[idx+1] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:spacers[idx] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:views[idx+1] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:spacers[idx] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        if (idx+1 == views.count-1) *stop = YES;
    }];

    //Make all the spacers have the same width
    [spacers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *spacer, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:spacer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:spacers[idx+1] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        if (idx+1 == spacers.count-1) *stop = YES;
    }];
}
```

This gave the following result with four different width labels,

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar. I'll post what I did later.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to achieve this is to use the method...

`constraintWithItem: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: multiplier: constant:`

To space the sub-views centres evenly across the superview, constrain the `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` of the sub-view to the `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` superview and use multiplier variable to space them...

```
CGFloat multiplier = (2.0 / (count - 1)) * position
```

Where `count` is `array.count` and `position` is the views index within `array`. This spaces the views evenly, however the first and last views would not be aligned as requested...

[image: UIViews spaced but not aligned!]

In order to align the first view correctly we simply set the `constant` to `frame.size.wdith / 2`.

In order to align the last view correctly we simply set the `constant` to `-(frame.size.width / 2)`...

[image: First and Last fixed]

Getting closer, but the spacing is a bit out of whack, so we need to use the `constant` and offset again. First we need the total width of the first and last view together...

```
UIView *viewFirst = array[0];
CGFloat widthFirst = viewFirst.frame.size.width;
UIView *viewLast = array[array.count - 1];
CGFloat widthLast = viewLast.frame.size.width;
CGFloat offset = widthFirst + widthLast;
```

Now we can use this, combined with `count` and `position` to offset all the other views...

```
CGFloat middle = (count - 1) / 2; // work out the centre of the array
CGFloat constant = ((offset / 2) / (count - 1)) * -(position - middle);
```

Put this all together in one method...

```
- (void)addConstraintsToView:(UIView *)view position:(NSInteger)position count:(NSInteger)count offset:(CGFloat)offset {

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:nil
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:view.frame.size.width]];

    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:nil
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:view.frame.size.height]];

    CGFloat multiplier = (2.0 / (count - 1)) * position;
    CGFloat middle = (count - 1) / 2;
    CGFloat standard = ((offset / 2) / (count - 1)) * -(position - middle);
    CGFloat constant = (position == 0) ? view.frame.size.width / 2 : (position == count - 1) ? -view.frame.size.width / 2 : standard;

    [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.mainView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                             multiplier:multipler
                                                               constant:constant]];

    [self.mainView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.mainView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0]];

}
```

So in `viewDidLoad`, calculate the offset and iterate through your views array calling this method each time...

```
UIView *viewFirst = array[0];
CGFloat widthFirst = viewFirst.frame.size.width;
UIView *viewLast = array[array.count - 1];
CGFloat widthLast = viewLast.frame.size.width;
CGFloat offset = widthFirst + widthLast;

for(NSInteger i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    UIView *view = array[i];
    [self.mainView addSubview:view];
    [self addConstraintsToView:view position:i count:array.count offset:offset];
}
```

Hey presto...

[image: UIViews horizontally spaced to their centres!]

EDIT:
Just noticed this isn't quite right, as when the first and last views are a different widths it won't offset correctly but hopefully you get the idea (this works perfectly if they are both the same)

Comment: You're assuming that the shared ancestor and the views have a fixed width. Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: And kudos for adding graphics. :)

Comment: This should work fine for a variable width shared ancestor, but agreed, if the sub views widths aren't fixed it fails. With this many variables you might be better overriding layoutSubviews and calculating the frame for each view here instead of using constraints.